# ZeroMQ linker error C++

Tags: c++, zeromq

I get the following error:

"Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_zmq_init referenced in     function "public: __thiscall zmq::context_t::context_t(int)" (??0context_t@zmq@@QAE@H@Z) ZeroMQPlay.obj ZeroMQPlay"

With this C++ code:

```
include "stdafx.h"
include <zmq.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 zmq::context_t ctx(1);

 return 0;
}
```

Heelp!

Comment: Could you please format your question, so code is in a code block.

Comment: Thanks Dirk and Aatch, I wasn't sure how to comment. New to this place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the linker about the ZeroMQ library. If you've built ZeroMQ as a VS project, the easiest way is to add the ZeroMQ project to the solution containing your own project and mark your project as dependent on it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems better than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Afaiu you're supposed to build the zeromq library first, and link it with your app.

Comment: I've built ZeroMQ, apart from include directive, what else needs to be done to link it in? I noticed "-lzmq [libraries]" in the doco. #rustyc++

Comment: PS I have included an additional dependency explicitly to "C:\zeromq\lib\libzmq.lib" this solved my issue. Thanks guys.

Comment: I guess you can add something like #pragma comment(lib,"fullpath\zmq.lib") to your source, but normally you're supposed to specify it in project options.